# Click button after RecyclerView onSwipe

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-swipe

I have a `RecyclerView` with an `ImageButton` and a `TextView`. I implemented swiping with `ItemTouchHelper.Callback`: the `TextView` is moved to the right and the `ImageButton` is flipped, showing a bin icon.

I want to be able to click on the `ImageView` in order to confirm the removal of the element, but then the `ViewHolder` comes back to its idle state.

I think it is because `RecyclerView` captures the touchEvent and it does not reach the `onClickListener` in the button. Any ideas?

Comment: Add a `log` statement to the callback and see if in fact the button press is being captured. At this point we know as much as you do.

Comment: No, the onClickListener of the button it is not captured, because the ItemTouchHelper intercepts the touchEvent and resets the viewHolder to its original position.

Comment: Then this seems to be the thing you're looking for: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback.html

Comment: Hy @user2776742, did you solve it?